# saving a canvas, bitmap with drawn circles

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have the following class below which extends View and has the onDraw method overridden to draw cirles on a bitmap which has been loaded in.

The bitmap loads successfully and is displayed on the screen. When the user touches the screen, a circle is drawn.

I have a floating Action Button that compresses the bitmap into a byte[]. This byte[] is then sent to another Activity to be displayed. Unforunately, the resulting bitmap does not have any circles in place.

canvas is a local object within onDraw and mCBitmap and tCanvas are global variable so that the method saveImage can access the data.

Can anyone tell me why none of the circles are copied to the resulting bitmap?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.graphics.PointF;

/**
 * Created by MatthewW on 14/06/2017.
 */

public class TouchView extends View {

    private static final String TAG = TouchView.class.getSimpleName();
    Bitmap bgr;
    File tempFile;
    private byte[] imageArray;
    private Paint pTouch;

    Context context;

    private SparseArray<ColouredCircle> mPointers;
    public int x;
    public int y;


    int circleCount;
    int radius;
    protected byte [] data;

    Bitmap mCBitmap;
    Canvas tCanvas;




    public TouchView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        this.context = context;

    }



    public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context,attr);
        Log.e(TAG, "inside touchview constructor");

        this.context = context;

        radius = 70;
        circleCount = 0;



        copyReadAssets();

        imageArray = new byte[(int)tempFile.length()];


        Log.e(TAG, "imageArray has length = " + imageArray.length);



        try{

            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);


            int i = 0;

            while (dis.available() > 0 ) {
                imageArray[i] = dis.readByte();
                i++;
            }

            dis.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageArray, 0, imageArray.length);

        if(bm == null){
            Log.e(TAG, "bm = null");
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "bm =  not null");
        }



        mPointers = new SparseArray<ColouredCircle>();


        bgr = bm.copy(bm.getConfig(), true);





        bm.recycle();

        pTouch = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        // pTouch.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT));
        pTouch.setColor(Color.RED);
        pTouch.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        pTouch.setStrokeWidth(5);




    }// end of touchView constructor




    private void copyReadAssets() {

        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        tempFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "bodymap.jfif");
        try {
            in = assetManager.open("bodymap.jfif");
            out = context.openFileOutput(tempFile.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

            IOUtils.copy(in, out);

            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);



        Log.e(TAG, "about to draw bgr ");
       // canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;



        Rect frameToDraw = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
        RectF whereToDraw = new RectF(0, 0, width, height - 300);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr,frameToDraw,whereToDraw, null);




        if(mPointers != null) {

            Log.e(TAG, "mPointers.size() = " + mPointers.size());

            for (int i = 0; i < mPointers.size(); i++) {

                PointF p = mPointers.get(i).getPointF();
                x = (int) p.x;
                y = (int) p.y;

                pTouch.setColor(mPointers.get(i).getColour());


                canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, pTouch);




                mCBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bgr.getWidth(), bgr.getHeight(), bgr.getConfig());

                tCanvas = new Canvas(mCBitmap);

                tCanvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);

                tCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, pTouch);

                tCanvas.drawBitmap(mCBitmap, 0, 0, null);






            }

        }






    }//end of onDraw





    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        switch (me.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
                /*int ai = me.getActionIndex();
                PointF pt = new PointF(me.getX(ai), me.getY(ai));
                mPointers.put(me.getPointerId(ai), pt);

                Log.e(TAG, "mPointers.size() = " + mPointers.size() + "me.getPointerId(ai) = "
                                 + me.getPointerId(ai) + " me.getX(ai) = " + me.getX(ai) + " me.getY(ai) = " + me.getY(ai));*/

                int ai = me.getActionIndex();
                PointF pt = new PointF(me.getX(ai), me.getY(ai));

                ColouredCircle cc = new ColouredCircle(pTouch.getColor(),pt);

                mPointers.put(circleCount, cc);

                circleCount++;

                invalidate();
                return true;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                /*int pid = me.getPointerId(me.getActionIndex());
                mPointers.remove(pid);*/
                return true;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                /*for (int i = 0; i < me.getPointerCount(); ++i) {
                    PointF pt = mPointers.get(me.getPointerId(i));
                    pt.set(me.getX(i), me.getY(i));
                    invalidate();
                }*/
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }



    public void showToastMessage(String mess){

        Toast.makeText(TouchView.this.getContext(), mess.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public  int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }




    public  void setRadius(int r) {
        radius = r;
        invalidate();
    }


    public void setCircleColour(String colourMode){


        if(colourMode.equalsIgnoreCase("RED")){

            pTouch.setColor(Color.RED);

        }else if(colourMode.equalsIgnoreCase("BLUE")){

            pTouch.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        }else if(colourMode.equalsIgnoreCase("GREY")){

            pTouch.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        }

    }



    public byte[] saveImage(){



        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mCBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
        data = bos.toByteArray();
        try {
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if ( data == null){
            Log.e(TAG, "data in touchview before save clicked is null");
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "data in touchview before saved clicked is not null and has length + " + data.length);
        }

        return data;

    }

}//end of class
```

[EDIT1]

I have changed my onDraw() and saveImage() methods to the following below. The image is now saved with the circles in place.

However, the bgr image is very small and in the top left of the screen, (the rest of the screen is black). The circles are in the correct place as they are in the original, it is just the bg image in not full screen size.

How can i make the bg image copy to the resulting Bitmap as full size?

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);



        Log.e(TAG, "about to draw bgr ");
       // canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;



        Rect frameToDraw = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
        RectF whereToDraw = new RectF(0, 0, width, height - 300);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr,frameToDraw,whereToDraw, null);




        if(mPointers != null) {

            Log.e(TAG, "mPointers.size() = " + mPointers.size());

            for (int i = 0; i < mPointers.size(); i++) {

                PointF p = mPointers.get(i).getPointF();
                x = (int) p.x;
                y = (int) p.y;

                pTouch.setColor(mPointers.get(i).getColour());


                canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, pTouch);





            }

        }






    }//end of onDraw
```

.

```
public byte[] saveImage(){

        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels - 300;

        Bitmap  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //Bitmap  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bgr.getWidth(), bgr.getHeight(), bgr.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        this.draw(canvas);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
        data = bos.toByteArray();
        try {
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if ( data == null){
            Log.e(TAG, "data in touchview before save clicked is null");
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "data in touchview before saved clicked is not null and has length + " + data.length);
        }

        return data;

    }
```

.

Here is a pic of the Activity that allows the user to place circles on the image. The bg image is full screen.

[image]

Below is a pic of the output in the next Activity where the image with circles is turned into a byte[] and displayed. As you can see the bg image is not full screen but the cirles are in the correct positions.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onDraw(...)`, change:

```
Rect frameToDraw = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
```

To:

```
Rect frameToDraw = new Rect(0, 0, bgr.getWidth(), bgr.getHeight());
```

One reason you don't have this issue when you are displaying the image in `onDraw(...)`, when `onDraw(...)` is called by the framework could be that the `Canvas` object supplied by the framework is hardware accelerated by default, if you have a target sdk >= 14 ([source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html), second paragraph, first sentence)

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329538/canvass-density), when a canvas is hardware accelerated, it seems its density is set to 0. However, if you'll call `Bitmap.getDensity()` on your field `TouchView#bgr`, you'll see that it won't be 0. That's because bitmaps when created, have the density of the current device's screen.

Next, you drawed your high density bitmap (on my device the density is 320 ppi) on your 0 ppi Canvas --> it will be drawn to look bigger.

However, in saveImage, you create a `Bitmap` from scratch, then you create a `Canvas` from that bitmap, and then you supply this canvas to call `draw(...)`. This new canvas you just created will not be hardware accelerated, and will also have the density of your newly created bitmap (320 ppi, in my case).

When you'll draw your body map image in `onDraw(...)`, you will draw it on this Canvas with 320dp, the same as your image.

This would still work fine, however you specify that you want to draw a region of screenWidth x screenHeight, assume 1920x1080, from your body map, which is most likely smaller, let's assume 1000x600, with `frameToDraw`.

What will Android do in this case? Well, `Canvas#drawBitmap(...)`'s Javadoc tells us the following:

> Note: if the paint contains a maskfilter that generates a mask which
>   extends beyond the bitmap's original width/height (e.g.
>   BlurMaskFilter), then the bitmap will be drawn as if it were in a
>   Shader with CLAMP mode. Thus the color outside of the original
>   width/height will be the edge color replicated.

Which basically means: I'll take your 1000x600 and draw your pixels as they should be drawn, and the rest of the pixels until 1920x1080 I'll fill up with some color of my choosing (probably black or white, or transparent?)

Now, you say, through `whereToDraw` that you want your 1920x1080 region to be mapped to a 1620x1080 region. To do this, android will further scale down your bitmap, rendering the `bodymap` even smaller.

The simplest solution to this is to specify the actual dimensions of your bitmap, in `onDraw(...)`, when creating your `frameToDraw` region.

Also, if these code fragments are testing code, it's fine, but please be sure to follow the guidelines mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html), when working with `onDraw(...)`, when you'll clean up your code.

The most important points would be that:

- your really shouldn't allocate object in your `onDraw(...)` methods, since they could get called very often, and this will kill your garbage collector. (i.e. frameToDraw & whereToDraw - you can preallocate these in the constructor)
- you can get a bitmap of your screen more easily by utilizing the drawing cache of the view.

Just change your `saveImage` to:

```
public byte[] saveImage() {
    //reder the view once, in software.
    buildDrawingCache();
    //get the rendered bitmap
    Bitmap bitmap = getDrawingCache();

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
    //destroy the drawing cache, to clear up the memory
    destroyDrawingCache();

    try {
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (data == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "data in touchview before save clicked is null");
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "data in touchview before saved clicked is not null and has length + " + data.length);
    }

    return data;
}
```

See:

- [View#buildDrawingCache(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#buildDrawingCache(boolean))
- [View#destroyDrawingCache(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#destroyDrawingCache())
- [View#getDrawingCache(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache())

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, Thanks for such a detailed answer. I think i need to do much more reading about android graphics. It works fine now! I'll also make those changes to place the objects inside the constructor. Thanks again!